# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Selector' Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Since migrating to Swift 3.0 on this line :

```
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: Selector())
```

I have the error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Selector' with no arguments`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you **want to set an action**:

```
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: #selector(test))

func test(){

}
```

Or if you **don't want to set an action** use:

```
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
```